# struggling with timer in android

Tags: java, android, timer

All I am looking to do is run some function 5 seconds after the app starts.  However i keep getting a "force close" after 5 sec.  Is timerTask even the correct function to be using in a situation like this? How about if i want to press a button later in the program, and have an event occur 5 seconds after user presses the button?

```
package com.timertest;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class timerTest extends Activity {

Timer timer = new Timer();
TextView test;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    timer.schedule(task, 5000);
}
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        test.setText("task function run");
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A TimerTask will run on a background thread but you're trying to change UI. You want to run your operation on the UI thread instead. Android traditionally uses messages posted to a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do this. A Handler will not create a new thread, when used as shown below it will simply attach to the same message queue that your app uses to process other incoming UI events.

```
public class Test extends Activity {
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private TextView mTest;

    private Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mTest.setText("task function run");
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to also implement onDestroy() to remove mTask from the handler, in case the user leaves the activity before the 5 seconds have passed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute some code after 5 secs try the following...

```
 new CountDownTimer(5000,5000) 
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            }
```

`@Override
        public void onFinish() {
                     // DO YOUR OPERATION
        }
    }.start();`