# Timers- Async Task or Threads

Tags: java, android, timer

I wanted to know what is the best way to disable a button for a certain amount of time. When the user uses other buttons to go to other pages, the timer will not be reset and the button will still be disabled.

There are many different ways i have read about async tasks, threads. However i am very unsure which is the best way to do this.

I want the timer to keep running while user selects other pages in the app. if the person tries to press the timer before the timer is up it will not work.

Many thanks,

Comment: A scenario would be: The user presses the button, a timer starts. The button will be **disabled** for 20 minutes. An example if - the user goes to the information tab on the app then comes back to the page. The timer should still be running and the button pressed for the timer should be disabled, unless a second button is pressed to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

To schedule a task for a time i use `Timer` class, with the method `schedule`

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
            // your code here
    }
}, 2000 );
```

After 2000 miliseconds (2 seconds) the method run, will be executed. I hope this help =)

Comment: Thanks, I know how to implement a timer once a button is pressed. I want to know how to keep it running, when a person opens a new activity. i want the timer still to be running and when the user comes back to the timer. there will be a visual display

Comment: That sounds more like a Service (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), other options can be BroadCast Receiver (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can see (from your comment to one of the answers) that you are aware that AsyncTask should not be run for a long time. The reason is because AsyncTasks are tied to the activity (since it is generally an inner class of the activity) and holds a reference to it. Because of this Android cannot GC the Activity while the AsyncTask is running which is kind of one of the core concepts of Android. This will lead to memory leaks in time. There are workarounds to avoid this but Android specifically introduces the concept of services for this and I'll explain this shortly.

Using a thread is also not a good idea as you generally end up creating threads inside the class where you need them as a result of which it holds a reference to that class and cannot be GC'd. Threads hold an advantage when certain long running tasks of the activity are going on and the Activity is necessary to be in the foreground. In your specific case, since you will be opening several other pages, Android would want to GC the original activity - thereby negating the advantage of threads.

Services are designed to be long running processes in the background and represent the server in a client-server architecture. The service can monitor the state of an object until the service is killed which happens only under low memory conditions. So even if the activity (or fragment) holding the button is GC'd by Android, you can design the service to remember the time left only after which even if a new instance of the original activity (or fragment) is instantiated, the button will be enabled.

Comment: Thanks, The timer also needs to be shown on the UI therefore i was not sure about using services. As service don't interact with the user interface.

Comment: Where I can get examples of service implementation and reading material on services?

Comment: The best documentation available is of course at the Android developers website. You can find some of the best complete project with code examples on Commnware's Github page under the title cw-omnibus. The projects there are the companion source code to Mark Murphy's excellent book "The busy coder's guide to Android development" published by Commonsware. The Commonsware subscription costs like some $40 or so for a year and you get every edition of the book released during that year. It's the most comprehensive book for Android and by far the best.

Comment: I'm providing the links to the projects they have specifically under services but you should check out the rest as well
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Service

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner at threading, Async tasks make it super easy. It is basically a wrapper for a timer that allows you to do "pre" and "post" and "during" activities. Once you are comfortable with the concept and are ready to get rid of the 'fluff' code, move to using Timers.

Comment: Thanks, will this be suitable for a timer that is longer than 20 minutes? As I have read async tasks should be used for small time limits.

Answer (score 0):

For simple changes to the UI, use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).  Disable the button and post a delayed `Runnable` to the handler to re-enable it.  `AsyncTask` would be overkill, and `Timer` would be inappropriate since you should only touch the UI from the UI thread.

You'll need to cancel the `Runnable` task when the user leaves the activity.  To make it appear that the timer is still running when the user is in another activity, save the essential state (i.e., the timer duration and start time) so the task can be posted again (or the UI updated to show that it's finished) when the activity resumes.  See the docs on [recreating activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Edit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575289/1953590) to a related question gives a bit more detail.